# Update row with difference between current row and a previous row

Tags: mysql

I am facing some difficulties to get the delta values :

```
id  value  delta
1   929     928
2   947     18
3   950     21
4   952     23
```

**Delta** Column should updated with the difference between the **value**  of consecutive row from the same table.

I mean,
    In second row Delta value should be `[947 - 929]=18`
    In Third row Delta value should be `[950 - 947]=3`
    In Fourth row Delta value should be `[952 - 950]=2` etc.

BY default **929** is always second parameter.That's why it's creating issue.
I used the Following query.Is there any problem with this?

```
update table_name tt1 left outer JOIN table_name tt2 ON  tt1.value>tt2.value set
tt1.delta = (tt1.value-tt2.value);
```

Comment: Edit your question again... Looks some weird formatting

Answer (score 0):

When you are doing multiple table updates (and even though this is the same table, because you are using it as a reference it's a multi-table update) you don't generally do JOIN clauses (per the mysql documentation here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html).

You can do something like this:

```
UPDATE table_name tt1, table_name tt2
SET tt1.delta = (tt1.value - tt2.value)
WHERE
tt2.id = (tt1.id + 1)
```

A good debugging technique is to change the UPDATE to a SELECT and verify that the delta fields are what you want:

```
SELECT tt1.*,  (tt1.value - tt2.value) AS delta
FROM  table_name tt1, table_name tt2
WHERE
tt2.id = (tt1.id + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming id really is incremental (with no gaps)

```
SELECT x.*
     , y.value-x.value delta
  FROM my_table x 
  LEFT 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.id = x.id + 1;
```

...and consider whether there's really any merit in storing values that can be easily derived from other values.

Answer (score 0):

```
Update T1
SET T1.delta = Ta.value - T1.value
FROM T1
INNER JOIN T1 Ta ON T1.id + 1 = Ta.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query.

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME T
SET T.DELTA = (T.VALUE - (SELECT VALUE FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE ID = T.ID - 1))
WHERE T.ID > 1;
```

This query should work if your table has a record for each and every id starting from 2.

This query will not update the first record.

Answer (score 0):

```
update t t1  
set delta=value-coalesce((select value from 
                    (select id,value from t) t2 
                    where t2.id<t1.id 
                    order by t2.id desc limit 1),1)
```

[SQL filddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c0140/1)